# registration page does not save data in mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem with the registration page, the html page works correctly but after clicking the submit button the data is not saved in mysql and the browser shows the whole php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="register.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="OIP.jpg">
    <title>Strona testowa</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="home.html">Home</a>
  <a href="news.html">News</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <div id="acc">
      <a href="login.html">Login</a>
      <a href="register.html">Register</a>
    </div>
</div>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
  username: <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
  email: <input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
  password: <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">


</form>
      

        
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php

$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Tworzenie połączenia z bazą danych
$conn = new mysqli(host, dbusername, dbpassword, dbname);

// Sprawdzenie czy połączenie się udało
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Tworzenie zapytania SQL
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";

// Wykonanie zapytania SQL i sprawdzenie czy się udało
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

// Zamknięcie połączenia z bazą danych
$conn->close();

?>
```

I have searched for help in different places but nowhere found the answer which may be a problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.